# What is an easy way to make a selectable uitable for blackberry?

Tags: java, blackberry, listfield

I am new to blackberry development.  I miss my iphone uitableviews. If there anything similar for the blackberry?  It needs to hold a variable amount of cells and the cells need to be selectable which will look a new view.  I was looking at ListField but I can't figure out how to actually load the cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This site has a good example you can pick apart -> http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=898

The one thing you will need to add to `MyListField`

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {

    // Push screen 
    MyScreen myScreen = new myScreen();
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen( myScreen );

}
```

This will catch that click or touch event

Comment: Cool! it seems to work pretty well.  The only thing is, do you know if it's possible to have the text on the cells to be more than 1 line?

Comment: i never tried putting in a lot of text, but i would guess that you would have to split the text up yourself and call `g.drawText()`, in `drawListRow()` which is in the callback class, multiple times and position the lines yourself.

Comment: This post has a solution -> http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Can-drawText-wrap-text-into-multiple-lines/m-p/258817#M42493